# Can I enter a country using just my seaman's book?

Tags: visas, passports, uk-citizens, identity-cards, angola

I am a UK citizen, working offshore of Angola. The shipping agent took my passport when I went through the Angolan port authority, to join my vessel. The Angolan authorities have my passport, as my work visa is getting renewed.

Can I go onshore into Angola with my seaman's book and wait in a hotel for the return of my passport?

Edit: i am not joining a vessel. I am remaining on land in the country without the visa

Comment: I am leaving a vessel. Not going onto a vessel and that answer doesn't explain that.

Comment: I believe that the answer should say "join or leave" everywhere it says "join," in which case it should answer your question.

Comment: Since you already have a work visa and you have already applied for a renewal and they do know about it and you are a seaman it might be possible. Maybe a query to them will answer this?

Comment: Perhaps someone who knows for sure can make the edits phoog suggested.